# Python, Pandas Dataframe - creating a derived column with conditional statements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame with 50 columns and 50k rows. There is one column with measurement data that needs correcting with a calibration factor. The factor is an integer value to be added or substracted. There are multiple (10ish) measurements in the same column of measurement data ['T_calibrated'], they all have an unique serial number in a seperate column ['serial']

I can calibrate a single sensor as follows using .where:

```
data['T_calibrated'] = data['T_uncalibrated'].where(data['serial'] == 12345)-2.7
```

12345 is the unique serial number
-2.7 is the calibration factor.

How would I write this in a more generic form so that I can add the unique calibration factor associated with each serial number and add this all as a single combined column ['T_calibrated']. So far I'm getting stuck with brute force ways. I'm sure there must be some very elegant way to do this.

I have a second dataframe with the serial number and calibration factor that can be looped or compared with ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

Close after posting my question I saw the light.

I joined the two dataframes on the serial numbers preserving the original index of the original (because I want that). Then I created another column just subtracting the two values. I didn't know how to add "inplace=True" with the join statement.

Here's my code:

```
calibrated_data=data.join(calibration_dataframe.set_index('serial'),on='serial')
calibrated_data['T_calibrated'] = calibrated_data.T_uncalibrated - calibrated_data.calibration_factor
```

Answer (score 0):

You describe two data frames structured as below.  Simplest approach is to merge them then calculate required column from merged data frame.

```
import numpy as np

serial = [f"{a}{ord(a)}" for a in list("abcdef")]

df = pd.DataFrame({"serial":np.random.choice(serial, 50), "T_uncalibrated":np.random.randint(20,30,50)})
dfs = pd.DataFrame({"serial":serial, "calibration":np.random.randint(-2,2,len(serial))})

df.merge(dfs, on="serial").assign(T_calibrated=lambda d: d["T_uncalibrated"]+d["calibration"])
```

#### sample output

| serial | T_uncalibrated | calibration | T_calibrated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c99 | 20 | -2 | 18 |
| c99 | 27 | -2 | 25 |
| c99 | 28 | -2 | 26 |
| c99 | 28 | -2 | 26 |
| c99 | 20 | -2 | 18 |
| c99 | 22 | -2 | 20 |
| c99 | 24 | -2 | 22 |
| c99 | 24 | -2 | 22 |
| d100 | 21 | -1 | 20 |
| d100 | 26 | -1 | 25 |